# Storing text box value into database using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, text, textbox

I am new to vb and am trying to store a text box value into database. I have 3 text boxes and I need to store all these values to my database. This is my code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim accessconn As New  _
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "avalanche.mdb")
        Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO register(name,id,username) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "')", accessconn)
        conn.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        accessconn.Close()
```

and am getting an error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are running a 64 bit OS Version.

The setup for Visual Studio has to be changed to `x86` from `AnyCPU`.  Within Visual Studio :

- Select "Project"
- Select "Properties" for your project
- Select "Compile"
- Select "Advanced Compile Options"
- Select "x86" instead of "AnyCPU"

Comment: I can't see an option to change from AnyCPU to x86 :(

Comment: what version of your visual studio?

Comment: Visual studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

Comment: I'm sorry, I have try to browse on internet Advance Compile Options for your version but can not find one. I don't have VS 2012. Better wait for another answer or try find it yourself.